# Can I upload two versions of the application for review in the iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have 1.1 version of my application already in review process now I also want to upload 1.1 version of the application for review process. 
So that if anything bad happens to version 1.1, I could directly release 1.2 without going through review process (as it would have been done already). So, I want to send two version of my same application to appstore review process.

Is it possible. If yes then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only upload one version of the application for the App Store review process. But You can have multiple versions in your application in TestFlight. We can even have greater version of the application available on TestFlight from the current version which is under review.

You can refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot submit multiple versions of the same app when it is already in review. If you're unsure of the current version, you can anytime remove the binary and upload new version. Also to avoid app rejection, you can go through the App Review Guidelines for once.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/

Also in the below link you can find new rules and changes in existing ones :
http://www.appstorereviewguidelineshistory.com/articles/2017-06-08-new-rules-following-wwdc-2017/

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the current version in review to put another version.